# AWS EMR Spark - get CSV And use with SparkSql api

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, emr

```
//download file  csv
ByteArrayOutputStream downloadedFile = downloadFile();

//save file in temp folder csv   (
java.io.File tmpCsvFile = save(downloadedFile);

//reading
Dataset<Row> ds = session
        .read()
        .option("header", "true") 
        .csv(tmpCsvFile.getAbsolutePath())
```

**tmpCsvFile saved in the following path**:

> /mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1511379756333_0001/container_1511379756333_0001_02_000001/tmp/1OkYaovxMsmR7iPoPnb8mx45MWvwr6k1y9xIdh8g7K0Q3118887242212394029.csv

**Exception on reading**:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist:
>   hdfs://ip-33-33-33-33.ec2.internal:8020/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1511379756333_0001/container_1511379756333_0001_02_000001/tmp/1OkYaovxMsmR7iPoPnb8mx45MWvwr6k1y9xIdh8g7K0Q3118887242212394029.csv;

I think the problem, is that the file is saved locally and when i try to read through spark-sql api it can't find the file. 
I already tried with sparkContext.addFile() and doesn't work.

Any solutions?

Thanks

Comment: the file /mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1511379756333_0001/.. seemns to be a local file. Did you tried reading using file:/// option . Try this Dataset<Row> ds = session.read().option("header", "true").csv(file:///tmpCsvFile.getAbsolutePath())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark support large number of filesystem, for reading and writing.

- Local/Regular (file://)
- S3 (s3://)
- HDFS (hdfs://)

As a standard behaviour if no URI is specified spark-sql will use hdfs://driver_address:port/path.

The solution of adding file:/// to the path, **can work only in the client mode** , in my case (cluster) it doesn't.
When the driver creates the task for reading the file it'll be passed to an executor to one of the node that doesn't have the file.

**What we can do? write a file on Hadoop.**

```
   Configuration conf = new Configuration();
   ByteArrayOutputStream downloadedFile = downloadFile();
   //convert outputstream in inputstream
   InputStream is=Functions.FROM_BAOS_TO_IS.apply(fileOutputStream);
   String myfile="miofile.csv";
   //acquiring the filesystem
   FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(dest),conf);
   //openoutputstream to hadoop
   OutputStream outf = fs.create( new Path(dest));
   //write file 
   IOUtils.copyBytes(tmpIS, outf, 4096, true);
   //commit the read task
   Dataset<Row> ds = session
    .read()
    .option("header", "true") 
    .csv(myfile)
```

Thanks, any better solution is welcome